# What happens when you end a Sql Server Service Broker message "with error"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I am trying to figure out how to deal with errors using Sql Server Service Broker.

I have read that there is no real "poison message" control in the Service Bus other than to just stop processing.

For my system, this would be very bad (we would get quite behind on messages).

I have seen an example that says it deals with this by using `end conversation with error <error code>`

But I can't seem to find out what this actually does in the queues or where the error is recorded.

If anyone knows what calling a "with error" on end conversation does, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It places an Error message on to the queue rather than an EndDialog message. Books online states 'Service Broker drops any other messages for this conversation currently in the transmission queue.' which I take to mean that this message replaces any messages that haven't yet been sent.

The error number and message get placed in the message body.

Comment: More specifically, the message sent back to the initiator is of the message type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error`

Comment: "drops any other messages for this conversation currently in the transmission queue": you have to consider there are always two queues, your and the remote one. When you issue End dialog (with or w/o error) any pending message in *your* queue is dropped. In other words, after you issued End Dialog you are guaranteed that you will never Receive any message on that dialog, therefore the application state pertinent to that dialog can safely be erased.